# Determine format of uncompressed ZIP file with ffprobe

Tags: ffmpeg, compression, zip, ffprobe

I am working on a project where I need to handle ZIP archives that contain media files. Specifically, I have two files, **video1.hevc** and **video2.mp4**. For testing purposes, I created two ZIP archives from these files using different compression levels:

A compressed ZIP archive using the command: `zip -1 compressed.zip video1.hevc video2.mp4`
An uncompressed ZIP archive using the command: `zip -0 uncompressed.zip video1.hevc video2.mp4`

When I use ffprobe to analyze the compressed ZIP file with the command `ffprobe compressed.zip`, I receive the expected error message indicating that the input data is invalid.

However, when I analyze the uncompressed ZIP file with `ffprobe -show_format uncompressed.zip`, it surprisingly identifies the format as **hevc**. This result is unexpected since I anticipated a similar error message as with the compressed archive, given that **uncompressed.zip** is still a ZIP file and not a direct media file.

My question is: Is there a way to use ffprobe or ffmpeg to accurately determine that I am dealing with an uncompressed ZIP file rather than a media file? My goal is to reliably identify whether I'm dealing with a media file. Any insights or suggestions on how to achieve this with ffprobe or ffmpeg, or alternative approaches for handling such files, would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `file` should be able to identify a Zip file by its file-header. You could combine it with `ffprobe` to differentiate between the two cases.